# Wordpress Plugin Uninstall not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, uninstallation

Uninstall Hook is not working proper as when I am uninstalling the plugin, the table are not being dropped. Please help me with this. Here is the following code I am using. Please tell me what I am missing.

```
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_db_uninstall' );


function plugin_db_uninstall() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."user_master";  
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."candidate_master";
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");


}
```

Full Code

```
define('TXTFOLDER', plugins_url()."/candidate_section/txtfiles");

function candidate_install () {
    if (!file_exists(TXTFOLDER)) {
        mkdir(TXTFOLDER, 0777);
    }
}


function candidate_section_create_table()
{

    global $wpdb;

        $sql = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$wpdb->prefix."user_master`
        (
          `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  `email` varchar(255) NOT,NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
        dbDelta($sql);

        $sql1 = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$wpdb->prefix."candidate_master` 
        (
          `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  `position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        )  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

        dbDelta($sql1);

}


function plugin_db_uninstall() {
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."user_master";  
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."candidate_master";
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");


    }


if (is_admin()) { 
add_action('admin_menu', 'candidate_menu');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'candidate_install');
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'candidate_section_create_table' );
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_db_uninstall' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about the cause, but I can see two things. One is that you could remove all 3 `register_*_hook` from inside `is_admin()` and leave them outside any conditional.

*PS: why do you have **two** `*_activation_hook`s?*

The other is using the file [`uninstall.php`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80350/12615) instead of `register_uninstall_hook`. I'm not finding the link where I saw the pitfalls of the hook discussed, but since a long time I only use the `uninstall.php` method.

There's [this note in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook), but no further reference on the *why* is given:

> Emphasis is put on using the 'uninstall.php' way of uninstalling the plugin rather than register_uninstall_hook.

And a link to this WordPress Answers: [Uninstall, Activate, Deactivate a plugin: typical features & how-to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25910/12615).
But check [all the results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22uninstall.php%22) over there.